# Odd failure to create SQL Server CE .sdf file in LINQPad query

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, linqpad

I'm using LINQPad with a custom assembly, behind which there is an SQL Server CE database which may or may not exist at the time. The custom assembly uses Entity Framework code-first with automatic migrations, and includes a simple initialiser inheriting from `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` which will create the database if it doesn't exist. I've been working with it for a couple of weeks and it's been working quite nicely.

This morning, after a small glitch proved frustratingly difficult to diagnose until I realised that a migration had happened between two events in the log, I decided it'd be nice if the database's own log table noted when a migration had been applied. To that end, I added a couple of lines to the `Seed()` method in the initialiser to instantiate the generic repository/unit-of-work container I've been using, add a record to the logs table, and commit the changes back to the database. The repo has a flag to indicate that it does not own the underlying context, so I can be sure that it doesn't dispose the context I'm then going to try to use.

Now, if I change the model (I'm testing by repeatedly commenting and un-commenting one of the `DbSet` properties on the context class) then a record is inserted to note that a migration took place. Exactly what I wanted. However, if the .sdf file doesn't exist, LINQPad gives me the following error:

> The underlying provider failed on Open
>   InnerException: The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database.

While the error message is perfectly self-explanatory (the file can't be found because it isn't there) what isn't clear is why it doesn't just create the file like it did before. What's *really* odd about this is that if I re-compile the custom assembly and then run the LINQPad query again, then LINQPad will create the `.sdf` and continue happily. This happens even when the changes to the assembly are irrelevant. In testing, I have run the query, watched it fail, then added a single blank space to the end of a comment in the repository class, re-compiled it, and then run the query again... and it worked. I am completely at a loss to explain how that should have made a difference.

At this point it may be worth mentioning that the "custom assembly" I'm dealing with here is LINQPad's own "My Extensions" file. Yes, I wrote a data context with code-first automatic migrations initialisation and a generic specification-pattern transactional repository in my extensions file. Yes, I realise that's probably not what it's meant for. I was bored, and wanted to test something. Anyways, this may be causing something strange somewhere. It may not, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.